# Angular CLI - Generate external CSS file from SASS

Tags: css, angular

I have the following settings in my angular-cli

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css","assets/scss/app.scss"
      ],

"defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {}
  }
```

the above compiles all SCSS into CSS and inserts into a `<style>` tag in the page. How do I make the CLI generate an external CSS file, so I can `<link>` it?

Comment: found solution yet?

Comment: @user2290351No, I just go ahead with the inline style tag